# Undo last action using jquery

Tags: jquery

HI friends I want to make editable div in which user can type text when text reaches to defined height of div the font size will go decrease to `14px` after that when user continue type text and again reach defined height then an alert will come that will say 'stop typing' and user cant type unless until he delete some text in div.... I know this story is too long but i know i can defiantly get the answer here i have tried something you can find below or you can see fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/JW4Qt/3/

**SCRIPT**

```
$('.divContent').keydown(function(e){

        var heigh = $(this).height();
        if (($(this).height()) > 200)
        {   
        var font = $('.divContent').css('font-size');
        font = parseInt(font);

        $(this).css('font-size',''+font - 2+'px')

        if(($(this).css('font-size')) <= '14px' && heigh > 200)
        {
            $(this).css('font-size','14px')
            font = 14;

            /*alert('stop')*/

            }

            }
        })
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="divContent"  contenteditable="true" autocomplete="off">
    Start typing here</div>
```

Thanks in advance guys.. :)

Comment: Surely you should be checking the length of the text input, not how much space it takes up..?

Comment: for your reff please go through this link http://www.scribbler.com/bestsellers/save-water-drink-champagne and click on `ADD TEXT` button and start typing in any box and press `enter` again and again then you can understand what i am looking for...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to seperate both if conditions and pass another condition in your first if condition.

```
$('.divContent').keydown(function(e){

    var heigh = $(this).height();
    if (($(this).height()) > 200 && $(this).css('font-size') >= '16px')
    {   
        var font = $('.divContent').css('font-size');
        font = parseInt(font);

        $(this).css('font-size',(font - 2) + 'px')
    }

    if(($(this).css('font-size')) <= '14px' && heigh > 230)
    {
        $("span").html("<b style='color:#f00'>STOP TYPING...</b>" );
        $(this).css('font-size','14px')
        font = 14;
        if(e.keyCode==8)
        {
         $("span").html("<b style='color:#0f0'>START TYPING...</b>" );
         return true;
        }
        else
        {
         return false;      
        }
    }


})
```

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JW4Qt/6/) for demo

Comment: Thanks for help @Amit Soni its working as i required but there is something in your code I want to ask about if you don't mind. What is `keyCode==8`

Comment: keycode is basically a number of keyboard keys for e.g. if you press backspace in your keyboard , the keycode of backspace is 8. a nice article about [javascript keycodes](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/).